# SEO Url not changing upon form submission

Tags: forms, url, seo, form-submit

Am using SEO URls to load my pages ie http://www.mywebsite.com/p/page1/100 but am having a problem with my search form. When I click submit, instead of the entire url changing to the stated one in the form, it just appends the variables to the url eg http://www.mywebsite.com/p/page1/100?p=search&q=Any+Query+String+here.

My question is, how do I replace the entire URL with the form variable instead?

Here is my form code:

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="get">
    <input type="text" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value=this.defaultValue;" name="q" value="Search" /> 
    <input type="hidden" value="search" name="p" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="submit" />
      </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I solved it using a hack I think???

Apparently if I append a variable to the action url, this will force the browser to load the new url instead of append the form variable to the existing url.

Eg.

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>?p=search" method="get">
<input type="text" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value=this.defaultValue;" name="q" value="Search" /> 
<input type="hidden" value="search" name="p" />
<input type="submit" value="Search" class="submit" />
  </form>
```

This worked for me but I dunno if it's the right way to achieve this or it's a hack.